# create $scope while loop

Tags: angularjs, variables, for-loop, angularjs-scope

i dont know how can i create scope inside loop like in javascipt var data + [i], is possible i think, and i want push some data to scope like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents.length; j++) {
                            if ($scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[j].kode_tanya == $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[i].kode_tanya) {
                                console.log(true);
                                $scope.data+[i].push({
                                    key: $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[j].kode_jawab,
                                    y: $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[j].jumlah
                                });
                            };
                        }
                        console.log($scope.data+[i]);
                    }
```

please help, thank's

Comment: Do you mean to say `$scope['data'+i].push`

Comment: If you need to create a new scope within the loop, you will need to call a function within the loop which prototypically inherits from the parent scope ($scope).

Comment: @Chandermani can i binding 'data+[i]' ?

Comment: @trunks175 how it's work, sorry i'm beginner

Comment: This is standard javascript. Object are basically hash maps. The value can be referenced using `.` or `[key]`

Comment: but, i tried and did'n work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanna generate variables in scope dynamically so for that see the below template. You need to modify your code a bit.

Few things keep in mind.

[.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is the function of array. Here you are trying to add variable in scope.

scope is json variable so `.push()` method will not work.

To add any new property in json there are two methods as @Chandermani mentioned in comment. Here you can go with the key as a string method so that you can generate string dynamically and can use that string as a property name of scope object.

Check below template and compare with your's.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[j].kode_tanya == $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[i].kode_tanya) {
            console.log(true);
            $scope['data' + i] = {
                key: $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[j].kode_jawab,
                y: $scope.laporanDataKuisioner.contents[j].jumlah
            };
        }
        ;
    }
    console.log($scope['data' + [i]]);
}
```